# difference between mouseReleased and mouseClicked

Tags: mouseevent, mouselistener, java

searching on the JAVA api document, i knew the difference between the mousePressed and mouseClicked. but.. the mouseClicked method involves both pressing and releasing so the action is done after the releasing the mouse, i don't find much difference with mouseReleased.

when i tried myself, i found that pressed and clicked are different because the time of action is different, but it's not the case between clicked and released.

my program is about drawing oval at the selected point in canvas

i'm looking for help in this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is not a very big difference, but [`mouseClicked`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html#mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent)) happens when:

> Invoked when the mouse button has been clicked (pressed and released) on a component.

Instead [`mouseReleased`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html#mouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent)):

> Invoked when a mouse button has been released on a component.

So if you click outside your application, drag the mouse on the application and release it you have a `mouseReleased` event, but you don't have a `mouseClicked` event, because it was pressed outside the application.

Comment: Isn't your last paragraph indicating a big difference?

Comment: its like he said, if u drag to far (whether or not its off the application enitrely) mouseReleased gets called after mouseDragged; mouseClicked doesnt

Answer (score 1):

**mouseClicked** work when you press and release the mouse button in the same coordinates, obviously inside the JComponent.
**mousePressed** work as soon as press the mouse button in the JComponent.
**mouseReleased** work as soon as release the mouse button, provided that has previously press in the JComponent.

While you press the mouse button in the JComponent, no matter the final coordinate for to release the mouse button, it could even be outside the JComponent.
In all cases no matter the length of time between pressing and releasing.

HCL from Perú

Answer (score 0):

MouseDragged, generated when the user moves the mouse while holding down a mouse button;

MouseReleased, generated when the user releases one of the buttons on the mouse;

void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)

Invoked when a mouse button has been released on a component.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).